# Google Cloud Speech-To-Text API response doesn't return words

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

I am trying to implement Speech-To-Text in my application using Google Cloud Speech-To-Text API with Python. I get the transcription correctly, however the response contains only the transcript and confidence, but not the separate words. If I try to access the words, I get an empty list.

For accessing the results, I use the following code:

```
best_alternative = result.alternatives[0]
word = best_alternative
transcript = best_alternative.transcript
confidence = best_alternative.confidence
print(f'Transcript: {transcript}')
print(f'Confidence: {confidence:.0%}')
```

Printing out `best_alternative.__dict__` gives me transcript and confidence, but not words. Is there any particular way of accessing the words in transcript or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**:
Initially, I was initializing the recognition configuration like this:

```
config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=RATE,
    language_code=lan_code)
streaming_config = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
        config=config,
        interim_results=True,
        enable_speaker_diarization=True)
```

With this configuration, the returned response didn't contain words, only transcript and confidence. Then I changed my configuration to this:

```
config = speech.RecognitionConfig()
config.sample_rate_hertz = 16000
config.language_code = 'en-US'
config.encoding = speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16
config.enable_speaker_diarization = True
```

This eventually gave me words alongside with transcript and confidence. The words can be accessed using:

```
response.results[0].alternatives[0].words[i].word
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Cloud Speech-to-Text API REST [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest), `speech.recognize` method returns speech recognition response along [SpeechRecognitionResult](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize#speechrecognitionresult) for each transcription result `results[]` object, whereas [SpeechRecognitionAlternative](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize#speechrecognitionalternative) retrieves `transcript`, `confidence`, `words[]` within a particular hypothesis.

Looking through the Python Google [google-cloud-speech](https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/index.html) library implementation, I admit that for genuine `SpeechRecognitionAlternative()` [class](https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/speech_v1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1.types.SpeechRecognitionAlternative) we can discover a list of word-specific information [WordInfo](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize#wordinfo) for each recognized word.

```
print("Words: {}".format(result.alternatives[0].words[0].word))
```

Comment: I have actually tried a similar piece of code before even posting here and I was getting a "List out of index" error. As I have written above already, printing result.alternatives.__dict__ prints out only transcript and confidence and no words[ ].

Comment: I found a solution and added it in the original post. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the update and glad to help you here. In particular, `results[0]` only gets you the first result of audio frame, assuming you're planing to iterate over the entire results I wrote my answer. If it was helpful to reach the desired goal then consider [accept/up vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up [RecognitionFeatures](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/v2/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v2#recognitionfeatures) you need to specify **both** `enable_word_time_offsets=True` and `enable_word_confidence=True`. With only time offsets requested `words` field was always empty for us.

Source: I've experienced this same problem with Cloud Speech-to-Text [gRPC API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/v2/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v2), WordInfo array was always empty. The answer provided in the **UPDATE** part of the question was a bit cryptic but led us to believe that this is some problem with default configuration values.

Answer (score -1):

I was working on this problem and after spending a lot of time, I realized that audio files must fulfill the speech.RecognitionConfig format. I took the FFmpeg library and converted my audio file according to the speech.RecognitionConfig format. When the conversation was complete, I simply passed the output file path for audioBytes conversation for recognitionAudio and got a speech-transcribed text. That's it.